# How can I find data on delisted stocks?

Tags: united-states, historical-data, research, history

I'm looking for a U.S. stock with the symbol AULT from about 1999.  How can I find information about delisted U.S. securities in general?  Particularly historical stock prices, market cap, company name, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a source of delisted historical data. Such data is typically only available from paid sources.

According to my records, AULT (Ault Inc) began as an OTC stock in the 1980s prior it having an official NASDAQ listing.  It was delisted on 27 Jan 2006.  Its final traded price was $2.94.  It was taken over at a price of $2.90 per share by SL Industries.

Source: Symbol AULT-200601 within Premium Data US delisted stocks historical price data set available from http://www.premiumdata.net/products/premiumdata/ushistorical.php

Disclosure: I am a co-owner of Norgate / Premium Data.

Answer (score 2):

In general you cannot. Once the security is no longer listed on the exchange - it doesn't have to provide information to the exchange and regulators (unless it wants to be re-listed). That's one of the reasons companies go private - to keep their (financial and other) information private.

If it *was* listed in 1999, and is no longer listed *now* - you can dig through SEC archives for the information.

You can try and reach out to the company's investors' relations contact and see if they can help you with the specific information you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  I'm sure there are quotes around somewhere--if nowhere else from newspaper listings.  Or did they stop listing stock quotes in the newspaper already in 1999?  They don't still list stock prices in the paper, do they?

Comment: @glenviewjeff I don't think they do, I don't know if they did it for all stocks in 1999 on a daily basis. Sounds like a huge waste of paper... Try WSJ archives?